# Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a una DB pero me sale error en el mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Mi código es este:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    if(!$id) {
        header('Location: /');
    }

    // importar la conexion
    require 'includes/config/database.php';
    $db = conectarDB();

    // consultar propiedades
    $query = "SELECT FROM propiedades WHERE id = ${id}";

    // obtener los resultados
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $propiedad = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
?>
```

Y el error es este:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_assoc(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tu consulta debería ser la siguiente.

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM propiedades WHERE id = ${id}";
```

Comment: Wow que error mas tonto. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 2):

Al margen de la respuesta que ya te dieron y debería solucionar el inconveniente actual me gustaría mencionar lo siguiente:

1. Evita el paso directo de valores a la estructura de la consulta

   - Usa [sentencias preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php)
   - De esta manera ya no vas a requerir sentencias tales como:

     - `"tu query ${variable}"` *esto hasta parece [`template strings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)*
     - `"tu query $variable"`
     - `"tu query".$variable`
     - `"tu query {$variable}"`

       - Que aunque son son *funcionales* involucran el riesgo de *inyección SQL*
2. En ningún momento evalúas los [posibles errores](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php#refsect1-mysqli.error-examples) que la query puede darte, para que de esta manera obtengas el mensaje de error exacto que impide consigas el resultado buscado

   ```
   if (!mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
       print_r(mysqli_error($db));
   }
   ```

   - El punto anterior te será útil mientras estés depurando pues te ayudará a identificar de manera mas rápida que es lo que provoca que tu código no *ande* a nivel de la query.

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, voy a investigar sobre las sentencias separadas y las voy a empezar a usar.